# Simulation of Transistor - Ltspice

Tags: transistors, pwm, simulation

I produced spwm to drive high side mosfet.
I made a simple note gate from a pnp transistor to receive the inverse of the signal I produced.
PWM-A/ is the opposite of PWM-A and both are 5V. So far everything is working normally.
When I connect the PWM-A/ signal to the base of the NPN transistor that triggers the bootstrap capacitor in front of it, the voltage on the PWM-A/ line drops to 1V. What could be the reason?

In the 1st photo, PWM-A/ signal is not connected to NPN transistor
In the 2nd photo, the 5V signal is working properly when the signal is not connected.
In the 3rd photo, the PWM-A/ signal is connected to the NPN transistor.
In the 4th photo, the same signal dropped to 1V

[image]

Source: My own study

[image]
Source: My own study

[image]
Source: My own study

[image]
Source: My own study

Comment: It doesn't look like you understand how BJTs work.  It's almost as if you expect the BJTs to function exactly like MOSFETs.  If you replace your BJTs with MOSFETs, your circuit will function how you want it to (except you should really right-click and pick a part# for your MOSFETs).  Otherwise you need to add base resistors to your BJTs and understand how the PN junctions in a BJT operate.

Comment: Your question can be simplified into asking why these two circuits in my following screenshot are different.  Can you see the difference?  It should be quite obvious:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6DLs.png